# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in Quick Union Implementaion in C

Tags: c, algorithm, malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int *id,N;

main()
{
    FILE* file=fopen("a.txt","r");
    int i,p,q,c;
    fscanf(file,"%d",&N);

    id=(int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        *(id+i)=i;

    while(!feof(file))
    {
        fscanf(file,"%d %d",&p,&q);
        if(!connected(p,q))
            unn(p,q);
    }
    fclose(file);
    c=1;

    while(c==1)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&p,&q);
        printf("%d\nYes(1) or No(0)    ",connected(p,q));
        scanf("%d",&c);
    }
}

connected(int p,int q)
{
    return((root(p))==(root(q)));
}

unn(int p,int q)
{
    int j=root(q);
    int i=root(p);
    *(id+j)=i;
}

root(int i)
{
    while(i!=(*(id+i)))
        i=*(id+i);
    return(i);
}
```

On compiling, no error message is displayed. However, when I try to execute this program, it says"Segmentation Fault (core dumped). Why does this happen?
As may have noticed, this is an attempt to implement the quick union.

The quick find was implemented without any hassle using the same file "a.txt" with only a few tweaks to this code. 
* The Yes or No is for the user's query.

Comment: Don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it doesn't do what you expect it to. Instead do `while (fscanf(...) == 2)`.

Comment: And you really should enable warnings, as the code you present will give a lot of those!

Comment: Seems like the perfect time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Seems also like a good time to start checking function return values.

Comment: @Dukeling The debugger said that`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048729 in root ()"

Comment: When you post the next question please ensure that you post ACTUAL code that you compiled

Comment: Given the amount of times that you have edited the code, coupled with the fact that it clearly does not even compile (even though you say it has despite lack of return types specified in your functions) it becomes harder and harder to try to help

Answer (score 3):

I would guess this is the problem

```
root(int i)
{
    int p;  
    while(p!=(*(id+p)))   <-- p uninitialised 
        p=*(id+p);
    return(p);
}
```

because `p` is uninitialised but you are using it as an offset in a pointer dereference. Even if it is not THE reason it is still a big problem.

You have since edited the question to leave

```
root(int i)
{
    int i;  
    while(i!=(*(id+i)))  
        i=*(id+i);
    return(i);
}
```

in which you redeclare an `i` variable locally as well as a `i` variable passed as function parameter.

Comment: You should really copy paste code directly - otherwise how are we to know what is a typo and what is code error??

Comment: I'll be sure to follow your advice from next time on.

Comment: @Alex The error here would be found if you had warnings enabled. While warning messages are not technically errors, they are often an indicator that you are doing something you should not be doing. If using e.g. GCC or clang, add at least the `-Wall` flag.